# .NET PrintDocument - Text gets cut off

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I have an application (C#, .NET 3.5) that writes receipts. They are usually printed with a small receipt printer with the .NET PrintDocument. The problem is the exception cases where I want to print with a regular printer. In these cases the text gets cut off. I wish to have a check or a switch to prevent this, but still keep the tight margins on the small printer.

What would be the best way of dealing with this? Can I do this without touching the graphics generation?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have set the Printer in PrintDocument, you might take a look at the present PaperSize using the value of:

`PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize`

Or maybe:

`PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was setting the printerDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.

Instead, I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32932466/953496)

```
private PrintDocument _printDocument = new PrintDocument();
private int _checkPrint;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _printDocument.BeginPrint += _printDocument_BeginPrint;
    _printDocument.PrintPage += _printDocument_PrintPage;
}

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printDialog=new PrintDialog();
    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        _printDocument.Print();
}

private void _printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the content of RichTextBox. Store the last character printed.
    _checkPrint = rchEditor.Print(_checkPrint, rchEditor.TextLength, e);

    // Check for more pages
    e.HasMorePages = _checkPrint < rchEditor.TextLength;
}

private void _printDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
    _checkPrint = 0;
}
```