# C# Printing Problem (RichTextBox)

Tags: c#, printing

I want to print the content of my RichTextBox (eintragRichTextBox)
I have now this code:

```
private void druckenPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    PrintDocument documentToPrint = new PrintDocument();
    printDialog.Document = documentToPrint;

    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(eintragRichTextBox.Text);
        documentToPrint.Print();
        documentToPrint.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(DocumentToPrint_PrintPage);
    }
}

private void DocumentToPrint_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(eintragRichTextBox.Text);
    float LinesPerPage = 0;
    float YPosition = 0;
    int Count = 0;
    float LeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    float TopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
    string Line = null;
    Font PrintFont = this.eintragRichTextBox.Font;
    SolidBrush PrintBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    LinesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

    while (Count < LinesPerPage && ((Line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
    {
        YPosition = TopMargin + (Count * PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Line, PrintFont, PrintBrush, LeftMargin, YPosition, new StringFormat());
        Count++;
    }

    if (Line != null)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
    PrintBrush.Dispose();
}
```

But it always prints me a blank site :(.. Anyone an Idea, why it is not working?
Or has someone a better code/Idea how I could achieve the printing?

Comment: why are you creating this: "StringReader reader..." before the documentToPrint.Print() ? I think you do not need it there. Aso, what happens when you debug?

Comment: I have not spotted your problem yet, but one thing is that if your RTB has enough text to fill more than one page you are going to find that it prints an infinite number of pages. You need to be declaring your Reader, Count and Line values outside of the scope of you PrintPage event... you also need to do some debugging, add some break points in and see what values are being set as expected and which are not

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425

Comment: hmm perhaps the code work, but it could be, that I don't have enough ink.. Will check it soon

Comment: hmm no, there is enough ink, I can print word documents with text.. And my RTB has not a lot of text, only a phrase sometimes.. And Debugging isn't working, don't know why..

Comment: fixed it! Now it works fine, was a small issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

got it..

on this Place:

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(eintragRichTextBox.Text);
    documentToPrint.Print();
    documentToPrint.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(DocumentToPrint_PrintPage);
}
```

I changed to:

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(eintragRichTextBox.Text);
    documentToPrint.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(DocumentToPrint_PrintPage);
    documentToPrint.Print();    
}
```

Now it works fine..

Also if someone needs to print content of a RichTextBox, you can use my code..

Comment: This will not print the document with style and it takes a long time to print a long text!

Comment: I wrote this code 4 years ago and the goal then wasn't to print it with style. Anyway thanks for providing a new variant in the answers.

Answer (score 7):

I tried [How to print the content of a RichTextBox control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812425) and it works like a charm.

You just have to create a custom `RichTextBox` and then it will print the whole text so fast and also keeps the style on the paper!

Code for creating custom `RichTextBox`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace RichTextBoxPrintCtrl
{
    public class RichTextBoxPrintCtrl:RichTextBox
    {
        //Convert the unit used by the .NET framework (1/100 inch) 
        //and the unit used by Win32 API calls (twips 1/1440 inch)
        private const double anInch = 14.4;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
            private struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            private struct CHARRANGE
        {
            public int cpMin;         //First character of range (0 for start of doc)
            public int cpMax;           //Last character of range (-1 for end of doc)
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            private struct FORMATRANGE
        {
            public IntPtr hdc;             //Actual DC to draw on
            public IntPtr hdcTarget;       //Target DC for determining text formatting
            public RECT rc;                //Region of the DC to draw to (in twips)
            public RECT rcPage;            //Region of the whole DC (page size) (in twips)
            public CHARRANGE chrg;         //Range of text to draw (see earlier declaration)
        }

        private const int WM_USER  = 0x0400;
        private const int EM_FORMATRANGE  = WM_USER + 57;

        [DllImport("USER32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage (IntPtr hWnd , int msg , IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp); 

        // Render the contents of the RichTextBox for printing
        //  Return the last character printed + 1 (printing start from this point for next page)
        public int Print( int charFrom, int charTo,PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //Calculate the area to render and print
            RECT rectToPrint; 
            rectToPrint.Top = (int)(e.MarginBounds.Top * anInch);
            rectToPrint.Bottom = (int)(e.MarginBounds.Bottom * anInch);
            rectToPrint.Left = (int)(e.MarginBounds.Left * anInch);
            rectToPrint.Right = (int)(e.MarginBounds.Right * anInch);

            //Calculate the size of the page
            RECT rectPage; 
            rectPage.Top = (int)(e.PageBounds.Top * anInch);
            rectPage.Bottom = (int)(e.PageBounds.Bottom * anInch);
            rectPage.Left = (int)(e.PageBounds.Left * anInch);
            rectPage.Right = (int)(e.PageBounds.Right * anInch);

            IntPtr hdc = e.Graphics.GetHdc();

            FORMATRANGE fmtRange;
            fmtRange.chrg.cpMax = charTo;               //Indicate character from to character to 
            fmtRange.chrg.cpMin = charFrom;
            fmtRange.hdc = hdc;                    //Use the same DC for measuring and rendering
            fmtRange.hdcTarget = hdc;              //Point at printer hDC
            fmtRange.rc = rectToPrint;             //Indicate the area on page to print
            fmtRange.rcPage = rectPage;            //Indicate size of page

            IntPtr res = IntPtr.Zero;

            IntPtr wparam = IntPtr.Zero;
            wparam = new IntPtr(1);

            //Get the pointer to the FORMATRANGE structure in memory
            IntPtr lparam= IntPtr.Zero;
            lparam = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(fmtRange));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(fmtRange, lparam, false);

            //Send the rendered data for printing 
            res = SendMessage(Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, wparam, lparam);

            //Free the block of memory allocated
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lparam);

            //Release the device context handle obtained by a previous call
            e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);

            //Return last + 1 character printer
            return res.ToInt32();
        }

    }
}
```

The main source includes  `PrintDialog, PrintPreviewDialog, PrintDocument, and PageSetupDialog`, but it works fine just with one `PrintDocument` control. So I've removed some extra codes just to shorten the useful part. But if you're interested to using them all, you can find the full code in the linked page.

```
    private PrintDocument _printDocument = new PrintDocument();
    private int _checkPrint;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _printDocument.BeginPrint += _printDocument_BeginPrint;
        _printDocument.PrintPage += _printDocument_PrintPage;
    }

    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog=new PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            _printDocument.Print();
    }

    private void _printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // Print the content of RichTextBox. Store the last character printed.
        _checkPrint = rchEditor.Print(_checkPrint, rchEditor.TextLength, e);

        // Check for more pages
        e.HasMorePages = _checkPrint < rchEditor.TextLength;
    }

    private void _printDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        _checkPrint = 0;
    }
```

Comment: One can not use set printerDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize and use this method. That is what my issue was.

Comment: Broken link.  I think this is the MSDN equivalent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996492(v=msdn.10)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code has a problem, it reprints the first page only because of the

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(eintragRichTextBox.Text);
```

in your `DocumentToPrint_PrintPage()`

Answer (score -1):

use that!

```
StringReader reader;
        int prov = 0;

        private void DocumentToPrint_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {


            if (prov == 0)
            {
                prov = 1;
                reader = new StringReader(eintragRichTextBox.Text);
            }
float LinesPerPage = 0;
            float YPosition = 0;
            int Count = 0;
            float LeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            float TopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            string Line = null;
```

....