# Printing HTML with PrintDocument

Tags: c#, html, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Printing  (RichTextBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399842/c-sharp-printing-richtextbox)

I am developing an application in C# that receives orders from our servers, which works fine, but I can't figure out how to print HTML exactly like it's viewed in the web browser. Normally one would use a web browser control and print that, but I need to be able to print in A4 and A5 paper format. I have searched a long time for a solution, but I can't seem to find it.

I am currently using code that prints rtf formatted text, which works, but it does not print the HTML like it is viewed in the browser, which is crucial.

**Edit:** I am currently using code that is displayed [on this page](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2009/07/10/Printing-RichTextBox-contents-in-C.aspx), with a few changes that allows me to print in A5 format by changing the PaperSize setting. Anything else I tried has failed to do what I wanted.

**Edit 2:** [Sample HTML](http://goo.gl/uoRKs) of what needs to be printed. Don't mind the messy code, this is purely to show what it should look like.

So, to sum it up;

- I need to be able to print HTML like it's viewed in the webbrowser
- I need to be able to print it in both A4 and A5 format

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share the code that you have so far? An example of what it looks like on the screen would be helpful as well.

Comment: Added a bit of info about what I currently use. As for the example, it is simply data in tables with a logo and pricing. Doesn't sound like much, but my boss demands it to be exactly like it's viewed in a browser.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I would print it out and try to match the print out. Hopefully that is agreeable. `An example of what it looks like on the screen would be helpful as well.` would still help.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome, but the HTML is very basic and is viewed the same in every browser I've worked with. As for the print out matching, the printer seems to print in A4 anyway. Is there no way of telling the web browser control to print in A5?

Comment: Are you doing this in C# or vb.net?

Comment: C#, as you can see by the tag. I will put it in my post too.

Comment: Why would this question be a duplicate? I don't ask for a solution to print rtf formatted text, I have that. I need to know how to print HTML in A4 and A5 format, since what I have now does not work properly for me in this particular situation. If anyone has a better way to do it than by printing it in rtf, I'll take it.

Comment: Could someone please help me? I've searched high and low for a solution to this, but unsuccessfully. I really need this to work.

Comment: Can you add a sample html that you are trying to print to the question?

Comment: Added a link for an example