# How to print rtf from richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, printing, richtextbox, rtf

I am creating a word procsessor, and I want to add a prInt control to it. I have a richtextbox, and I want that the full rtf of the richtextbox will be printed, not only the plain text.

How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Printing  (RichTextBox)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399842/c-sharp-printing-richtextbox)

Comment: Also, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425

Comment: Here is the VB.net version of above article.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811401

Comment: I have problem with the DLL creating: When I build the code, it creates vb file, and not DLL. How can I create DLL file from the code?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do it. It's far from being enough, so another suggestions are welcome...

My code opens cmd, and with it prints the file via wordpad.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & write.exe /p " + filepath)
```