# Formatting and printing Text in C#

Tags: c#, printing, formatting

This may be a very basic question, but I never managed to find something that quite covers my question.
I'm working on a program in C# that lets you select different options (Imagine a shopping list in which you can check different items) if you hit the print button, it is supposed to create a file that has a title, some basic information, all are provided by the program itself and than makes a list of basically everything you have selected. After this "page" is created, it should be send to the same "standard windows print menu" everything goes to when you hit the print button in any program.
I have never done anything like this before and I have no real clue where to start trying to format my texts, is there an elegant way you could do this?

Comment: Are you using or you have in mind any reporting tools that you would like to use, for example CrystalReports? FastReports? etc.?

Comment: Have you already created this file or do you need to not only print it but also create it?

Comment: Which type of program are you gonna create? For an example is it a web application?

Comment: @JackMorton Sorry, I don't know what that is. Is this some kind of tool that helps to format your text?

Comment: @mark_h It would have to be created first.

Comment: @codelahiru It's a Windows Forms Application, which has nothing else attached to it right now.

Comment: @jan what you can do is after you select all the options then navigate to another form and include your print button there. First start with simple step. Get selected items to another page. then you can add other content as you want. then take a look at how you can print it. did you write any code?

Comment: _..it should be sent to the same "standard windows print menu" everything goes to when you hit the print button in any program._ Well, that is just an illusion for the user. You are a programmer and really should know better! Each application has its very own ways to do a proper job in printing its data.. - And no, if you have no clue how you want to format your text, you just can't start..

Comment: If you want to have both a file and a printout with formatting RTF comes to mind although it should be noted that [printing rtf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399842/c-sharp-printing-richtextbox) is not exaclty well-supported out of the box..!